# Spring Cloud Consul Config not working with Spring Boot 2.6.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, consul

I tried to follow the new changes with the latests versions of Spring, where the bootstrap.yaml has been removed, and use the "spring.config.import" property, but I am not able to make my application work (discovery is working fine, but not config server). I am doing so many tries and errors, so it does not make so much sense to copy my current properties, but I will give all the details, so maybe someone is able to identify what is going on:

- In my POM, there is already the next dependencies: "spring-cloud-starter-config", "spring-cloud-starter-consul-all", "spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery" and "spring-cloud-starter-consul-config". Spring Cloud version is "2021.0.1" and Consul "3.1.0".
- Main class annotated with @EnableDiscoveryClient
- Using "application.properties-development", not YAML, and SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development
- Application name is "profiles"
- In my Consul instance, in the "Key / Value" section, I have the next structure: [Consul Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C38n4.png) (/config/development/profiles and JSON with the properties to load).
- It would be nice that, as with the Cloud Config Server, if no property file is found, it would allow me to run the application.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: I also struggled with consul after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.0. My problem was i was setting the wrong consul agent endpoint in the spring.config.import property. If your consul agent is running on localhost:8500 you can simply add spring.config.import=consul: